# How to Control Fling action of Listview

Tags: android

We have used Custom List View inside that one Text View and two Edit text present. I have put On Item CLick Listener On the Edit text Listener is set properly. What Is problem when fling action is happen then that listener is not setting. Is their any other Listener which can help me to control fling action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you can't control the flying action, you can listen the flying action:

`ListView.OnScrollListener` can listen the scroll action:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if(scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING){ //flying

    }
}
```

you can try this, hope it can help you -):

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have sort out the above issue by using TextWatcher.